# Angular UI Calendar Integrate with public Holidays ,Is there any Public Holidays API?

Tags: angularjs, calendar, google-api

I am using Angular UI Calendar ,using this link  [http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-calendar/]

Now we want to Integrate Calendar with Public Holidays , Suppose lets we are in India then Public Holidays of India show , 
So I just want to know is there such an API which give me JSON data for the public Holidays

Comment: The google calendar inform about public holidays. The google calendar has an open API.

Comment: Give me a link for that

Answer (score 2):

A other solution you can use, is Nager.Date the most European countries, United States and Canada is supported. It is a open source Project.

Other countries can submitted by the github project.

## Example (JSON - API)

**Request**

[http://date.nager.at/api/v1/get/{countrycode}/{year}](http://date.nager.at/api/v1/get/us/2017)

**Result**

```
[  
    {  
        "date":"2017-01-01",
        "localName":"New Year's Day",
        "name":"New Year's Day",
        "countryCode":"US",
        "fixed":true,
        "countyOfficialHoliday":true,
        "countyAdministrationHoliday":true,
        "global":true,
        "counties":null,
        "launchYear":null
    },
    {  
        "date":"2017-01-16",
        "localName":"Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",
        "name":"Martin Luther King, Jr. Day",
        "countryCode":"US",
        "fixed":true,
        "countyOfficialHoliday":true,
        "countyAdministrationHoliday":true,
        "global":true,
        "counties":null,
        "launchYear":null
    }
]
```

**Links**

- [API Documentation](http://date.nager.at/Api)
- [GitHub - Nager.Date](https://github.com/nager/Nager.Date)

Comment: Is there any API which will give Indian holidays. This one doesn't work with Indian country code.

Answer (score 0):

We find the solution and Google Calendar provide the JSON data you just need to provide correct country code
$scope.currentCountry= "is the country code "ex {'India':'indian','Denmark':'danish'}
$scope.start = Date from where you want the Holidays data
$scope.end = End Date

http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/'+$scope.currentCountry+'__en%40holiday.calendar.google.com/public/basic?alt=json&start-min='+$scope.start+'&start-max='+$scope.end